# Telegram Bot. How set command /cmd in user text input?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I need to create command (for example - /cmd). When user click on this command in list - bot set this command text(/cmd) in user input and user should input argument for this command. How to do this?

Example:
I have command /cmd. And when user input is - "/cmd parameter1" it goes to execute command with this parameter. I need to allow the user not to enter "/cmd" - it will add it automatically.

Comment: "bot set this command text(/cmd) in user input" -- Impossible. Telegram bot can't place text in 'input' field. If you wish to create some sort of auto completion, take a look at [Inline Keyboards](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardmarkup)

Comment: What if i need arguments to this command?

Comment: Could you please edit your answer and give an example? If you wish to add arguments, maybe an [Inline Bot](https://core.telegram.org/bots/inline) suits your case. Otherwise list all possible `/cmd` 'arguments' with an [Keyboard](https://core.telegram.org/bots#keyboards)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on question & comments;

> bot set this command text(/cmd) in user input

A regular Telegram bot can't place text in Input field. This is only possible with an [Inline bot](https://core.telegram.org/bots/inline).

If you wish to 'ask' the user a specific 'argument' based on the `/cmd` command. You could use an [Inline bot](https://core.telegram.org/bots/inline), an [Keyboard](https://core.telegram.org/bots#keyboards) to list all available 'arguments' or ask the user, and 'wait' for a reply.

You could also show all available command with an [Keyboard](https://core.telegram.org/bots#keyboards) and then change the keyboard to the available arguments with [on-the-fly updatable inline-keyboard](https://core.telegram.org/bots#inline-keyboards-and-on-the-fly-updating)